# @ManagementContextConfiguration usage with WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter doesn't work

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

I have a working Spring Boot 1.x application, configured with different management port and security (Basic Auth).
After migration to Spring 2.1 it is not working anymore.

See the code:

@ManagementContextConfiguration
  public class ManagementConfig {

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER)
static class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  public SecurityConfig() {
    super(true);  // disable defaults
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
          .withUser("admin")
          .password(encoder.encode("admin"))
          .roles(Collections.emptyList().toArray(new String[]{}));
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      RequestMatcher matcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**");

      http
        .authorizeRequests()
          .requestMatchers(matcher).authenticated();
    }
  }
}
```

My spring.factories contains

```
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.ManagementContextConfiguration=\
  com.test.config.ManagementConfig
```

During begugging, I can see that SecurityConfig instance created, but no configure() method called (as I see, there was a post-processor call in Spring Boot 1.x after ManagementConfig created...).

My application.yml contains:

```
management.server:
  address: localhost
  port: 18543
  security: 
    enabled: true
```

The problem with it, that I can access any management endpoint now with simple

```
curl http://localhost:18543/info
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue with separating 
@ManagementContextConfiguration
and 
@EnableWebSecurity
into 2 different file.